# Truffle Testing: Supplying method params of type 'struct'?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

The init method below takes a struct as a input parameter, which sets some state variables.

In the remix IDE, I can supply the struct as an array of values for each struct member e.g. `["My Little Pony","Hasbro",3]

If I try to test the method in the same way as a truffle unit test, it doesn't work, the params don't get set.  What is the right way to supply a struct parameter to contract method in truffle?

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract StructParams {

    struct createParams {
        string title;
        string creator;
        uint editionLimit;
    }

    string title;
    string creator;
    uint editionLimit;

   
    function initialize(createParams memory params) public {
        title = params.title;
        creator = params.creator;
        editionLimit = params.editionLimit;
    }
    function getTitle() public view returns(string memory) {
        return title;
    }
}
```

This is the truffle test that fails.

```
 it('insitializes', async() => {
    let sp  = await StructParam.deployed();
    let s = ["My Little Pony", "Hasbro", 2];
    
    sp.initialize(s);
    let retval = await sp.getTitle();
    assert.equal(retval,"My Little Pony");
    console.log("title", retval);
  })
```

The value returned by getTitle() is an empty string.

Comment: Did you eventually found a solution to this?

Comment: ultimately I migrated to hardhat so I don't know the solution for Truffle.  In hardhat it is not a problem to pass structs to smart contracts -- hardhat creates a "Typechain" type which makes it pretty simple to both send structs to smart contracts or receive structs as return params from smart contract functions.

Comment: didn't you forget to `await` the `sp.initialize(s);` invocation here?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly pass struct in the constructor or function or initializer. You can try this:

```
mapping (string => createParams) private info;
   function initialize(strng memory _title, string memeory _creator, uint _editionLimit) public {
       createParams storage data = info[_title];
       data.title = _title;
       data.creator = _creator;
       data.editionLimit = _editionLimit
    }
```

If you want to pass a struct as a parameter you can do it with the help of  ABIEncoderV2. For this refer below link

link: [https://medium.com/@dillonsvincent/solidity-enable-experimental-abiencoderv2-to-use-a-struct-as-function-parameter-27979603a879#:~:text=Solidity%20%E2%80%94%20Enable%20ABIEncoderV2%20to%20use%20Structs%20as%20Function%20parameters,-Dillon%20Vincent&text=Now%2C%20with%20the%20ABIEncoderV2%20enabled,from%20web3%20or%20another%20contract](https://medium.com/@dillonsvincent/solidity-enable-experimental-abiencoderv2-to-use-a-struct-as-function-parameter-27979603a879#:%7E:text=Solidity%20%E2%80%94%20Enable%20ABIEncoderV2%20to%20use%20Structs%20as%20Function%20parameters,-Dillon%20Vincent&text=Now%2C%20with%20the%20ABIEncoderV2%20enabled,from%20web3%20or%20another%20contract).

please tell me if this works.

Comment: "You cannot directly pass struct in the constructor or function or initializer." is demonstrably false.  You can pass structs between functions, or even to constructors, certainly when one contract method is calling another.  The problem seems to be maybe something related to the way in which Truffle passes struct parameters from javascript to  into Ethereum contracts.  And as I noted, this doesn't seem to be a problem in the remix ide, but it is in truffle.